# Chef immediately throws Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout on powershell_script

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I am experiencing a recurring, yet random, error. Sometimes this works but more often than not I get a timeout on a very simple `powershell_script` resource. Chef doesn't seem to wait the default timeout (3600 seconds) but immediately throws this exception. Is there something I'm missing here? How can I debug the 
`Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout`?

```
 ================================================================================
 Error executing action `run` on resource 'powershell_script[uninstall]'
 ================================================================================

 Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout
 --------------------------------
 command timed out:
 ---- Begin output of "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -File "C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20180924-2936-1r1bagl.ps1" ----                                                                     
 STDOUT: 
 STDERR: 
 ---- End output of "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -File "C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20180924-2936-1r1bagl.ps1" ----                                                                       

 ProcessId: 1664
 app_name: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
 command_line: "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -File "C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20180924-2936-1r1bagl.ps1"                                                                                 
 timeout: 3600

 Resource Declaration:
 ---------------------
 # In C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/documents/recipes/service.rb

   7: powershell_script "uninstall" do
   8:   only_if { ::File.exist?('C:\Documents\scripts\Uninstall.ps1') }
   9:   code <<-SCRIPT
  10:   "Trying to uninstall...."
  11:   . C:\\Documents\\scripts\\Uninstall.ps1 > C:\\Documents\\Uninstall.log
  12:   SCRIPT
  13: end
  14:
```

Answer (score 1):

What Chef version are you using specificly?

Though, if you would like to debug, I guess trying to pass your command directly into `Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd, :timeout => 3600)` is a good starting point.

However, after I google it a bit I have just found out that powershell resource used to have some issues like https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout/issues/86, https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/2348, so not sure if they have been fixed in newer version etc.

Therefore, an alternate solution to consider is using `dsc` script with Chef
( that is, https://docs.chef.io/resource_dsc_script.html with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/scriptresource ) which I think might be more reliable.

Comment: I find adding a ruby block with `sleep 1` before the `powershell_script` seems to mitigate the problem.

Comment: @ReedG.Law Ok great if that works. But it's quite interesting since it does not seem to be relevant to `powershell_script` resource for me. Did you have time figuring it out how `ruby_block` affect the `powershell_script`?